# could not preselect value programatically in p-multiSelect primeng

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

i would like to preselect a value programmatically in primeNg p-multiSelect, i navigate from a previous page send values from router and set value to multiselect from its [(ngModel)].
the preselect is based on value label , here is the code .

```
    <div class="p-col">
                    <p-multiSelect id="code" name="code" [options]="codes"
                                   [(ngModel)]="criteres.code"></p-multiSelect>
                </div>
```

here is the code that feed the [options]
:

```
codes: SelectItem[] = [];
```

in my typescript i set the value to the ngModel criteres.code in ngOninit , then the field of the multiselext is empty.

```
            this.criteres.code = this.versionSelected[0]?.code;
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Did you make sure that `this.versionSelected[0]?.code` contains the data you require when `ngOnInit` fires? Where do you assign data to `this.versionSelected`?